# Special zeta value and zeroes

Tags: nt.number-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, riemann-zeta-function

Are there known relationships linking special values of the Riemann zeta function or MZV (multiple zeta values, i.e. $\zeta(n_1, \cdots n_k)$ with $n_i \in \mathbb Z^+$) to the nontrivial zeroes of the Riemann zeta function?

I became curious of this because MZVs appear in Feynman amplitude calculations. For example, we find a $\zeta(3,5)$ in the $\phi^4$ theory of page 7 of [Francis Brown's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.09265). Also, $\zeta(3), \zeta(5)$ are seen from a quantum electrodynamics calculation for the magnetic dipole moment of a muon, as seen on page 164 of [this collaborative effort](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04822).

Mysticism should be avoided, but if the zeroes of the Riemann zeta say something about MZVs or just $\zeta(2n+1)$'s, then maybe the distribution of prime numbers says something about Feynman amplitudes.

Comment: $\zeta(2n+1)$ is expressed explicitly in terms of the zeros via the Hadamard product.  What more could you possibly want?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I simply didn't know about that formula (I'm aware of such a general expansion, but didn't know that it would work for $\zeta$). Is there a similar formula for multiple zeta functions?

Comment: According to this paper by Zhao (from 2000)  https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-05/S0002-9939-99-05398-8/S0002-9939-99-05398-8.pdf we don't even understand the trivial zeros of multiple zeta functions.  I don't know enough about functions of more than one complex variable to know if there is some generalization of Hadamard product.